# Не обучается персептрон

Tags: java, массивы, нейронные-сети

Проблема с обучение заключается в следующем. При подсовывание персептрону вручную он обучается и после определяет принадлежность точки. Но при считывании с файла столбца со значениями перестает реагировать. данные проверял все правильно поступают в массив.

Класс персептрон

```
import java.io.IOException;

public class Perceptron {
Reader rd = new Reader();
double[][] patterns;
double[] answers;
double[] enters;
double[] hidden;
double outer;
double[][] wEH;
double[] wHO;
//double[][] patterns = {{-23,17},{-19,-34},{-42,-3},{-43,34},{-45,-21},
{41,-14},{27,-18},{19,34}};
//int[] answers = {0,1,1,0,1,0,0,0};

Perceptron(double[][] patterns, double[] answers ) throws IOException {

this.patterns = patterns;
this.answers = answers;
    enters = new double[patterns[0].length];
    hidden = new double[3];
    wEH = new double[enters.length][hidden.length];
    wHO = new double[hidden.length];

    initWeights();
    study();


    double[][] input ={ {-43,-45}};
    for (int p = 0; p < input.length; p++) {
        for (int i = 0; i < enters.length; i++)
            enters[i] = input[p][i];

        countOuter();


        if (outer==1){

            System.out.println("Точка принадлежит прямой");
        }

        else{
            System.out.println("Точка не принадлежит прямой");
        }

    }

}

public void initWeights() {
    for (int i = 0; i < enters.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < wEH.length; j++) {
            wEH[i][j] = Math.random() * 0.2 + 0.1;
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < wHO.length; i++)
        wHO[i] = Math.random() * 0.2 + 0.1;
}

public void countOuter() {
    for (int i = 0; i < hidden.length; i++) {
        hidden[i] = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < enters.length; j++) {
            hidden[i] += enters[j] * wEH[j][i];
        }
        if (hidden[i] > 0.5) hidden[i] = 1;
        else hidden[i] = 0;
    }
    outer = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < hidden.length; i++) {
        outer += hidden[i] * wHO[i];
    }
    if (outer > 0.5) outer = 1;
    else outer = 0;
}

public void study() {
    double[] err = new double[hidden.length];
    double gError = 0;
    do {
        gError = 0;
        for (int p = 0; p < patterns.length; p++) {
            for (int i = 0; i < enters.length; i++)
                enters[i] = patterns[p][i];

            countOuter();

            double lErr = answers[p] - outer;
            gError += Math.abs(lErr);

            for (int i = 0; i < hidden.length; i++)
                err[i] = lErr * wHO[i];
            for (int i = 0; i < enters.length; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < hidden.length; j++) {
                    wEH[i][j] += 0.1 * err[j] * enters[i];

                }
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < hidden.length; i++)
                wHO[i] += 0.1 * lErr * hidden[i];
        }
    } while (gError != 0);
}
```

}

Собственно класс Main где осуществляем запуск и он зависает.

```
import java.io.IOException;

public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

   Reader test = new Reader();
    test.setInputFile("E:/Lab2_data (3).xls");
    // считываем номер колонки из консоли
    int ColumnNumber = 0;
            //Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(System.in.read()));
    //передаем номер методу read()
    test.read(ColumnNumber);

        double[][]patterns = test.getInput();
        double[]answers  = test.getOutputs();

    Perceptron p = new Perceptron(patterns , answers);

 }
 }
```

При следующем варианте все работает и персептрон осуществляет обучение , и проверяет в дальнейшем точку на принадлежность

```
import java.io.IOException;

public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    double[][] patterns = {{-23,17},{-19,-34},{-42,-3},{-43,34},{-45,-21},{41,-14},{27,-18},{19,34}};
    double[] answers = {0,1,1,0,1,0,0,0};
    Perceptron p = new Perceptron(patterns , answers);

}
}
```

данные ввел вручную

```
 double[][] patterns = {{-23.0,17.0},{-19.0,-34.0},{-42.0,-3.0},
{-43.0,34.0},{-45.0,-21.0},{41.0,-14.0},{27.0,-18.0},{19.0,34.0},{-34.0,-18.0},{-4.0,-26.0},{32.0,-23.0},{-2.0,-36.0},{37.0,-22.0},{27.0,47.0},{-1.0,38.0},{32.0,-48.0},{-36.0,-36.0},{0.0,-48.0},{9.0,-50.0},{27.0,15.0},{27.0,20.0},{5.0,-30.0},{18.0,9.0},{45.0,14.0},{49.0,-26.0},{-42.0,27.0},{-1.0,38.0},{0.0,7.0},{45.0,18.0},{-17.0,-50.0},{20.0,48.0},{27.0,24.0},{-31.0,-36.0},{41.0,28.0},{8.0,36.0},{-41.0,12.0},{-22.0,37.0},{-34.0,-23.0},{4.0,46.0},{-33.0,-35.0},{-24.0,-33.0},{7.0,-1.0},{-22.0,-35.0},{10.0,23.0},{24.0,-42.0},{-43.0,-45.0},{-40.0,29.0},{30.0,-12.0},{11.0,-7.0},{24.0,-1.0},{-16.0,31.0}};
    System.out.println(patterns.length);

    double[] answers = {0.0,1.0,1.0,0.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,1.0,0.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,0.0,1.0,1.0,0.0,1.0,0.0,1.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0};

    System.out.println(answers.length);
```

Происходит зависание программы на стадии обучения!

Comment: Видимо, при считывании из файла получаются другие данные в массивах `patterns` и `answers`. Проверьте содержимое массивов (в режиме отладки, либо через `Arrays.deepToString`). Также распишите подробнее, что означает «*зависает*»: что именно происходит, на какой строке кода.

Comment: Данные получаю верные... проверял выводом в консоль ,а зависает просто программа перестает вычислять.Всего из файла попадают 50 наборов чисел и 50 ответов

Comment: 50 наборов это немного. Раз уж вывели их в консоль, то попробуйте прописать их в коде как в последнем примере. Если ошибка воспроизведется без считывания в Excel, то можно будет код считывания убрать и сконцентрироваться на самом перцептроне.

Comment: Выдает ошибку  at Perceptron.study(Perceptron.java:87)
 at Perceptron.<init>(Perceptron.java:25)
 at Main.main(Main.java:22)

Comment: Включите полное описание ошибки (тип, сообщение) в сам текст вопроса (это можно сделать с помощью кнопки «править» под вопросом). Обязательно отметьте строку кода, на которой возникла ошибка.

Comment: Изменил описание! Ругается что вне предела, хотя на вход отдаю 51 элемент в одном и 51 элемент в другом

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/74793/discussion-between-default-locale-and--).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я немного уменьшил значение ваших весов и теперь корректировка весов более правильная. Вывод результата - [тут](https://ideone.com/0dwyrU)

```
 public static class Perceptron {
    double[][] patterns;
    double[] answers;
    double[] enters;
    double[] hidden;
    double outer;
    double[][] wEH;
    double[] wHO;

    static int MAX_ITER = 100;


    public Perceptron(double[][] patterns, double[] answers) throws IOException {

        this.patterns = patterns;
        this.answers = answers;
        enters = new double[patterns[0].length];
        hidden = new double[3];
        wEH = new double[enters.length][hidden.length];
        wHO = new double[hidden.length];

        initWeights();
        study();


        double[][] input = {{-43, -45}};
        for (int p = 0; p < input.length; p++) {
            for (int i = 0; i < enters.length; i++)
                enters[i] = input[p][i];

            countOuter();


            if (outer == 1) {

                System.out.println("Точка принадлежит прямой");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Точка не принадлежит прямой");
            }

        }

    }

    public void initWeights() {
        for (int i = 0; i < enters.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < wEH.length; j++) {
                wEH[i][j] = Math.random() * 0.2 + 0.1;
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < wHO.length; i++)
            wHO[i] = Math.random() * 0.2 + 0.1;
    }

    public void countOuter() {
        for (int i = 0; i < hidden.length; i++) {
            hidden[i] = 0;
            for (int j = 0; j < enters.length; j++) {
                hidden[i] += enters[j] * wEH[j][i];
            }
            if (hidden[i] > 0.5) hidden[i] = 1;
            else hidden[i] = 0;
        }
        outer = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < hidden.length; i++) {
            outer += hidden[i] * wHO[i];
        }
        if (outer > 0.5) outer = 1;
        else outer = 0;
    }

    public void study() {
        double[] err = new double[hidden.length];
        double gError = 0;
        int iteration = 0;
        do {
            iteration++;
            System.out.println("gError = " + gError);
            gError = 0;
            for (int p = 0; p < patterns.length; p++) {
                for (int i = 0; i < enters.length; i++)
                    enters[i] = patterns[p][i];

                countOuter();

                double lErr = answers[p] - outer;
                gError += Math.abs(lErr);

                for (int i = 0; i < hidden.length; i++)
                    err[i] = lErr * wHO[i];
                for (int i = 0; i < enters.length; i++) {
                    for (int j = 0; j < hidden.length; j++) {
                        wEH[i][j] += 0.01 * err[j] * enters[i];

                    }
                }
                for (int i = 0; i < hidden.length; i++)
                    wHO[i] += 0.01 * lErr * hidden[i];
            }
        } while (gError != 0 && iteration<=MAX_ITER);

        System.out.println("iteration==" + iteration);
        if(iteration==MAX_ITER+1)
            System.out.println();
    }
}
```